# Why is this code giving time limit exceeded?

Tags: c++, time

I want to pick out the element that occurs odd number of times in an array. I declared array of size INT_MAX from the heap and did away with segmentation fault but now it is giving tle. What can be done using the same algorithm ?

```
/* C++ code to find out the element that occurs odd number of times, given there is only one such element in the array */

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cin >> arr[i];
    int* a = new int[INT_MAX];  // declared a dynamic array
    fill_n(a, INT_MAX, 0);  //initialised to 0
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[arr[i]]++;    // for every particular value, that corresponding index value increases
    }   

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(a[arr[i]] % 2 == 1) {    //if that corresponding index value is odd, that's the answer
            cout << arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }
        delete[] a;
return 0;       
}
```

Comment: What is the OS and compiler?

Comment: You need to find a different approach.  Hint: what happens when you xor a number with itself?

Comment: Here's a better question: Why do you think you want to allocate `INT_MAX` elements?

Comment: @NathanOliver I know this logic, just tried a different approach this time.

Comment: Typically judges test for the most optimal solution.  Generally not using it will cause a TLE.

Comment: @underscore_d , I allocated INT_MAX elements since the range isn't defined, so the user could enter to any limit. Doesn't this have O(n) complexity ?

Comment: @Muskan Filling eight gigabytes with zeros can take many seconds if it doesn't fit in physical memory.

Comment: @Muskan Handling buffers of arbitrary size is not done by just making them all as large as possible in any real code.

Comment: If you know that exactly one number occurs an odd number of times, you can solve this using only two integer variables. Change your perspective a bit (subtle hint).

Comment: By the way, variable length arrays: `int arr[n];` are not part of the standard language, but an extension offered by some compilers.  When posting to online judges, prefer to use standard elements of the language.

Comment: Try using `std::map<element, frequency>`.  If the element exists in the map, increment the frequency; otherwise insert a new element.  At the end, traverse the map, printing elements that have an odd frequency.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
int* a = new int[INT_MAX];  // declared a dynamic array
```

Is going to allocate 2 billion integers, i.e. 8 GB of storage.  Which you are then going to access randomly.  Your system may have a hard time allocating that much storage, and even if it can, it may be impossible to actually read and write so much memory in whatever time limit is allowed.

You asked

> What can be done using the same algorithm ?

Nothing.  This algorithm is deficient and cannot be used in a practical way.  You will need a different algorithm.

Comment: _"...may be impossible to actually read and write to so much memory in whatever time limit is allowed."_ What does this mean exactly? Don't computer programs read and write more to than 8GB regularly? Who sets a time limit? Is it at compile time or execution time?

Comment: @AGNGazer: When people say they got "time limit exceeded" for simple quiz-style programs, it suggests they are executing them on a quiz platform, perhaps an online coding test or similar.  These tests are often run on "small" machines (perhaps VMs).  There are programs which use more than 8 GB of memory, but it still takes them considerable time (probably a minute or longer) to do anything useful with that much memory.  The raw memory bandwidth on modern CPUs is roughly 20 GB/s, but that assumes ideal conditions; OP's code is pessimal with regard to cache utilization, TLB, and more.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!